# Real ORM for Android does not create the database

Tags: android, realm

I decided to use Realm to parse `JSONArray` that I get from web, and store it in the database. But it seems that realm does not create the actual database file as I always get an empty array from when I call `realm.allObjects` , and I looked for a database file in my emulator and I didn't find any `databases` folder in data folder of the app. The interesting thing is that when I remove the `return` statement from

`if(pois == null || pois.size() == 0){
            loadPoisFromNet();
            return;
        }`

it loads items from net and shows them in the list as expected, but the other time when I open the `activity` it begins loading them from the web again and the size of items is always 0. 
Can anyone help me, please?

```
public class PoiListFragment extends Fragment implements PoiListAdapter.OnOpenMapClickListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    private Realm realm;
    private PoiListAdapter mAdapter;
    private ListView mListView;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public PoiListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).build();
        Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);
        realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poi_list, container, false);

        mListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.poi_listview);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initPoisList();
    }

    private void initPoisList(){
        RealmResults<Poi> pois = realm.allObjects(Poi.class);

        if(pois == null || pois.size() == 0){
            loadPoisFromNet();
            return;
        }

        mAdapter = new PoiListAdapter(getActivity(), pois, true, this);


        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        Log.d("testt", "size " + mListView.getCount());
    }

    private void loadPoisFromNet() {
        if(!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())){
            DialogUtils.showOfflineDialogAndFinish(getActivity());
            return;
        }

        showProgressDialog();

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (ApiRequest.getPoiListUrl(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        realm.beginTransaction();

                        try {
                            realm.createAllFromJson(Poi.class, response.getString("list"));
                            realm.commitTransaction();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            realm.cancelTransaction();
                        }

                        cancelProgressDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        cancelProgressDialog();
                    }
                });


        ApiRequest.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpenMapClick(int position) {
        Poi poi = mAdapter.getRealmResults().get(position);
        Utils.openMap(getActivity(), poi);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close(); // Remember to close Realm when done.
    }

    private void showProgressDialog(){
        progressDialog = DialogUtils.showTransparentProgress(getActivity());
    }

    private void cancelProgressDialog(){
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of this strange behavior of Realm myself.
The problem was in the example codes of the Realm. In all examples the `Realm` object is instantiated this way:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).build();
Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);
realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
```

I don't know why they instantiate it this way but it seems to delete all the previously saved data. Instead of this I just instantiated `Realm` object by calling `realm = Realm.getInstance(getActivity());` and everything worked fine!